# Where can I edit text on pcp page

Tags: custom-templates, pcp

How do I change this text
“This contribution is being made thanks to the effort of [contact name], who supports our campaign.You can support it as well - once you complete the donation, you will be able to create your own Personal Campaign Page!”

I’ve searched high and low - every tpl file in contribute/pcp etc
Is it hardwired somewhere?

Thanks all.

Comment: interesting timing - we have just had to do the exact same thing - clearly there is room for some improvements to the PCP options via the UI

Answer (score 2):

Lesley,

This is set in php and then assigned to tpl. It's being set from two places [CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php#L474) and [CRM/PCP/BAO/PCP.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/PCP/BAO/PCP.php#L431). Since its being assigned to tpl through php then its pretty simple and easy to change the text using either preprocess/buildform/postprocess hook by over-riding the tpl variable.

Here are list of lines that uses the variable to print the text

```
templates//CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl:177:    {if $pcpSupporterText}
templates//CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl:178:    <div class="crm-public-form-item crm-section pcpSupporterText-section">
templates//CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl:180:      <div class="content">{$pcpSupporterText}</div>
templates//CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.tpl:61:    {if $pcpSupporterText}
templates//CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.tpl:62:      <div class="crm-public-form-item crm-section pcpSupporterText-section">
templates//CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.tpl:63:        <div class="content">{$pcpSupporterText}</div>
```

If you not familiar with using php then you can JS to replace the text. Here is what i would do

1. Create a Main.extra.tpl under `templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/` (custom template directory or extension)
2. Add below snippet in Main.extra

Snippet:

```
{if $pcpSupporterText}
<div class='crm-pcp_supporter_text_replace'>
  <div class='content'>
    {ts}Text to print{/ts}
  </div>
</div>

{literal}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    CRM.$(function($) {
      $("div.pcpSupporterText-section .content").replaceWith($('.crm-pcp_supporter_text_replace .content'));
    });
  </script>
{/literal}

{/if}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep - no wonder I couldn’t find a tpl file!

Comment: LesleyJill i have updated my answer with a list where the variable is used.

Comment: Thanks so much for those links - I don't know how to use hooks, but I think I can override template variables... or maybe not?

Comment: I have copied Main.tpl to custom_templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution. I changed line 174 to  <div class="content">{ts}My text{/ts}</div>. I cleared templates_c directory and browser cache. But the text remains as original. Am I missing something? Really appreciate your help with this. Oh and I'm on wordpress

Comment: LesleyJill, I have updated my answer on how you can do it using tpl. Personally i would hate to over-ride core file because its a pain during CiviCRM upgrade and Main.tpl is an important file and keeps changing. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Lesley - better to write this in an extension rather than overriding a core file. You can place the below hook in any of your custom extension or create one using [civix](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/)

As Peter Davis said in the comment, we just made this changes for one of our client using -

```
function example_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main' && !empty($form->_pcpId)) {
    $form->assign('pcpSupporterText', 'your custom pcp text');
  } 
}
```